# How do you extract values from a doubly linked list?

Tags: java, object, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have a linked list of objects linked together with a first, last next, previous variable each representing the appropriate nodes in a list. This list works fine.

I'm now trying to add SUB values (a sub doubly linked list) to that. Each item in the parent list will contain its own doubly linked list.

I'm having trouble referencing an item in the original linked list.

Once you create a linked list of values, how do you then access them?

What i have:

```
public class Menu<E> {
private mNode first;
private mNode last;
private mNode previous;
private mNode next;
private int size = 0;

public Menu(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
    previous = null;
    next = null;
}

public Menu(E[] elements){
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        add(elements[i]);
}

private boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
}

public void add(E e){
    mNode currentNode = new mNode(e);

    if(isEmpty())
        first = currentNode;    
    else if (last == null)
        last = currentNode;
    else{
        last.next = currentNode;
        currentNode.previous = last;
        last = currentNode;
    }

    size ++;

}
```

The mNode class hasn't really been developed fully yet but its here for reference:

```
public class mNode<E> {
E element;
mNode<E> first;
mNode<E> last;
mNode<E> previous;
mNode<E> next;
int index;

public mNode(){

}

public mNode(E e){
    element = e;
}

}
```

So again, my question is, Once I've added a bunch of elements to the linked list, I can iterate through it and print them all out but how would I find and extract a specific menu item?

EDIT:

for clarity, lets say I have

Item 1 <> Item 2 <> Item 3 <> Item 4

All in the first list. I want to add subitem1 <> subitem2 <> subitem3 to the Item 2 in the parent list.

How do I get reference the mNode for Item 2?

In the main method once you create a

```
Menu list = new Menu();
list.add(values)  // adding all 4 menu items
```

You can't really do a list.get(Item 2) because Item 2 isn't a variable inside menu.

Comment: Assign unique id to each menu items!! and through id you can find extract a specific menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have additional methods to your menu objects e.g. `getByIndex(int n)` or `getByName(String name)` (or whatever other attribute are your menus accessible with). If you wish to support a `getByName()` functionality and if your menus are large using an additional structure like a `Map` might be something to consider.

The real question is why do you need to get a reference to a specific menu? Ideally a menu should have two responsibilies: a) draw itself and b) let the system know that its state changed (i.e. clicked). This is why almost all menu systems support some callback mechanism e.g. in Swing you can attach an `ActionListener` that lets you know that an action is performed on the menu and respond to that. Using this idea you would have something like this (this is not full code just a demonstration):

```
interface MenuListener {
    public void menuClicked(Menu m);
    // other type of handlers here, when menu state changes e.g. menuExpanded()
}

public class Menu {
    ...
    List<MenuListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MenuListener>();

    // this method will be called internally by each menu when it detects
    // that its state changed
    private void notifyListeners() {
        for (MenuListener listener : listeners) {
            // let all the listeners know this menu was clicked
            listener.menuClicked(this);
        }
    }
}    

// now when menu is created assign a listener to it
Menu item = new Menu(...);
item.addMenuListener( new MenuListener () {
    public void menuClicked(Menu m) {
        // do something with item here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write one more method in your Menu class `findMenu()`, which iterate the linkedlist from start to end if you element is found then it will return the that element

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from your design is what data will be in each node.

If you think about it, you need different data in different nodes. Sometimes you could have just a menu item and other times you could have a whole sub menu. The sub menu is another list like you have designed, so you will have a list of lists (or ...): this a tree structure.

For each of you nodes, you need to be able to ask "does this node have children?", "get the children", or "get the menu item". Once you have done this you can think about an OO design.

As you traverse your menu, you would find out what each node holds and decide what to do in each case.